# How to run `ng` in windows

Tags: cmd, angular-cli

I have installed `Angular-cli` locally. The path is `.../node_modules\@angular\cli\bin`. I see that there is an `ng` file at this path.

```
23/05/2018  09:03    <DIR>          .
23/05/2018  09:03    <DIR>          ..
23/05/2018  09:03             6,627 ng
```

I want to check the version of `angular-cli` but when I run `.\ng --version` in windows `cmd`, I get the error `ng is not a recognised command`.

How can I find `ng`'s version using `cmd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have installed `ng-cli` in the developer dependencies of the project, you cannot use it directly from the command line.

You have two options to use this:

1. Install it globally using `-g`
2. Use [`npx`](https://github.com/zkat/npx)

   ```
   npx ng
   ```

You can use npx from the project root to use the one that is included in project dependencies. `npx` will resort to downloading `ng` and running the rest of the command without polluting global namespace.

Comment: thanks. Installed `npx` globally and did `npx ng --version` at one directory level before `node_modules`